# bootstrap-fullscreen-select How to fire onClose event of each select option separately?

Tags: jquery

I am using select option full screen from http://craftpip.github.io/bootstrap-fullscreen-select/

I have 2 html select options :

```
<select id="select_month"  class="form-control mobileSelect" >
</select>

<select id="select_year"  class="form-control mobileSelect" >
</select>
```

Documentation show only fire onClose event for ALL select option. How to fire onClose event of each select option separately? I have tried :

```
<script>
$('.mobileSelect').mobileSelect({
    animation: 'scale',
    animationSpeed: 400,
    onClose: function(){

    },
   
    onOpen: function(){
        
    }
});

$('#select_month').mobileSelect({
    animation: 'scale',
    animationSpeed: 400,
    onClose: function(){
        var month1 = $( "#select_month" ).val();
        get_day_option(month1,year1);
    }
});

$('#select_year').mobileSelect({
    animation: 'scale',
    animationSpeed: 400,
    onClose: function(){
        var year1 = $( "#select_year" ).val();
        get_month_option(year1);
    }
});
</script>
```

But it shows Error : `This element is already Initialized`.
Seem I can't initialize `.mobileSelect` for more than 1 time.

Comment: Is this your *only* code?  You state "I can't init `.mobileSelect'` but your code doesn't init via *class* mobileSelect, it inits via `#id` - so you have some other code such as `$(".mobileSelect").mobileSelect()`

Comment: It *looks like* the library is auto-initialising based on `.mobileSelect` - remove that class from your `select`s such as `<select id="select_month"  class="form-control" >` so that it isn't auto-init'd

Comment: yes i have this too `$(".mobileSelect").mobileSelect()`

Comment: Well, that's your answer - you're initialising it twice as stated in the error `This element is already Initialized` - remove `$(".mobileSelect").mobileSelect()` or remove the class from your select so it isn't auto-init'd

Comment: i can't remove class, because class is required in order to use bootstrap-fullscreen-select plugin. I tried to remove `$(".mobileSelect").mobileSelect()`, it shows new error : `'Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined'`

Comment: I have added my full code on my question, `$(".mobileSelect").mobileSelect()` doesn't declare `'refresh'` property tho, seem `$(".mobileSelect").mobileSelect()` auto declare `'refresh'` property at behind the plugin

Comment: You'll need to create a [mcve] with all the `<script>` tags and css links.  I tried to find a CDN for your unmaintained plugin (from 2014) but wasn't successful. Removing the duplicate `.mobileSelect()` *is* the answer, but you don't say *where* the other error occurs - it could be that it's now working and `get_day_option` is failing.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: finally i manage to get it fixed, just don't use $(".mobileSelect").mobileSelect() refresh property will do. Thank you very much for your guides

Comment: Ok Finally I can use `refresh` property, just found out where is error `"refresh property"` come from, it is just because i forgot initialize `$('#select_day').mobileSelect`